# Flexible CMS for non-programmers

Tags: linux, content-management-system

I'm looking for a content management system that allows creating single pages out of predefined blocks flexibly. For example I have a "product" block that is used to show producs on a page and it may appear numerous times on one page with different contents. But I also might wanna use it on different pages. Also I have simply generic blocks like multiple column text blocks (1 col, 2 col etc.) where I just want to insert this kind of structure into the page and enter any text.

So I'm looking for a cms with someething like a building block / module concept for contents.
I'm already searching the web but there are so many CMSs that I can't look into every one.
So if anyone knows a solution that might be right for me, please tell me!

Technology-wise it just has to run on Linux. If it's OpenSource / free that's great, but I might also pay for it, if it offers the features I want.

Thanks for any hints in advance!

P.S.

Note that most important is/was a way to build page layouts dynamically. There are a few solutions (like ImpressPages) which allow building blocks in one row. But I need to flexibly create rows and columns of the layout.

Comment: The best fit I found so far is [Carrington Build](http://crowdfavorite.com/wordpress/carrington-build/). Other than that [TomatoCMS](http://www.tomatocms.com/) seems to be promising, but was not yet mature enough when I tested it.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [CushyCMS](http://www.cushycms.com/en):

- It takes less than 3 minutes to implement and doesn't require PHP or ASP.
- If you can add CSS classes to HTML tags, then you can implement CushyCMS.
- Since CushyCMS is a hosted CMS, there is no installation or maintenance either.
- No programming required.

[Also check out the DEMO video](http://www.cushycms.com/en/static/demo)

---

Other ***open source alternative*** is excellent [ImpressPages CMS](http://www.impresspages.org/), I really love it because of the ease of use it offers.

> ImpressPages is the next generation
>   CMS that enables you to develop an
>   effective and functional website in
>   one hour.
>
> ImpressPages is an open source
>   software. It can always be adapted to
>   you own needs.
>
> ImpressPages is:
>
> ```
> * Open source
> * Absolutely free
> * SEO friendly
> * Multilingual
> * User friendly
> ```

I would really like people to know about this great piece of software out there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! ImpressPages CMS looks interesting. Unfortunately it lacks dynamic columns. For example I would need to be able to draw a widget next to another one in the same row to create two columns, another one for three and so on. If I understand correctly different column layouts can only be created manually via template files. Since the page I'm creating has too many different of them that's not feasible, though.

Comment: @Bunkerbewohner: I am sure there must be some solution to what you are doing. You can put up a question to the ImpressPages team :)

Answer (score 3):

ImpressPages will have many columns since version 1.1.0 http://www.impresspages.org/news/impresspages-1-1-timeline/

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/)

Comment: I don't think Joomla is that easy for *non-programmers* :)

Comment: Thanks, I tested Joomla but couldn't find the features I am looking for so far.